# Javascript Related

Tags: javascript, background-color

Sir I am Having an Issue with this Code,Loop in the Following code is not work please provide possible solutions of this problem , the purpose of this code to auto change the background color but it does not comes in loop

```
var e1 = document.getElementById('top').style;
var code = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  code = code + 10;
  c = '#' + code;
  e1.backgroundColor = c;
}
```

Comment: your `code` variable isn't a valid HEX color code

Comment: Are you expecting to see all the different colors? Changes to the DOM don't get rendered until the Javascript completes. If you want to see continuous changes, you need to use transitions.

Comment: Please give me a proper solution of it thank u :)

Comment: Barmar sir it is Just End of the body so the page is rendered